# I have a problem with looping to more than one element using querySelectorAll?

Tags: javascript

I cant seem to make this function running I want a multiple items on HTML to show same day..

example

sunday
sunday
sunday

it shows only one Sunday don't got to other.. i think my loop is missing something

any ideas please

```js
function currentdaychange() {

    let weekday = ['Sunday',
        'Monday',
        'Tuesday',
        'Wednesday',
        'Thursday',
        'Friday',
        'Saturday']
    [new Date().getDay()];
    let items = document.querySelectorAll('.currentday');

    //document.querySelector('.currentday').innerHTML = weekday;
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        items[i] = weekday;
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(currentdaychange);
}

currentdaychange();
```

Comment: Did you perhaps mean `items[i].innerHTML= weekday`, just like in your commented-out code?

Comment: have you tried checking the content of `items`? you can try with `console.log()` or debugging the code.

Comment: To expand a bit on @Phil's comment, `item[i] = weekday;` simply puts a string into the `items` array. It does not modify any elements.

Comment: items[i].innerHTML= weekday worked thanks all for the effort.  especially phill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let days = ['Sunday',
        'Monday',
        'Tuesday',
        'Wednesday',
        'Thursday',
        'Friday',
        'Saturday'];
    let weekday = days[new Date().getDay()];
     document.querySelector('.currentday').innerHTML = days;
    document.querySelector('.currentday').innerHTML =   document.querySelector('.currentday').innerText.replace(weekday,'<span style="color:red">'+weekday+'</span>')
```

```html
<div class='currentday'>
</div>
```